# Setting the height to a div to a multiple of line height

Tags: css

How do you express the height of a div as a multiple of its line height in pure CSS without hard-coding line height or font size?

### Background

I have a box (a DIV) that contains status text. The text will sometimes span multiple lines and often need only one. The status is updated several (five) times per second and this causes the bottom border and everything below the box to "jump" up and down as the box changes size to fits its contents.

One solution to the jumping would be to set the min-height of the DIV to the height of two lines. Status text with more than two lines is rare so that degree of jumping would be acceptable.

Alternatively I could set the height to the exact height of two lines and use overflow:hide to truncate the text. That would eliminate all jumping at the expense of some information.

Which raises the question: How do I express height as a multiple of line height? The status text inherits its appearance from the global style sheet and does not know font size, family, line height, or anything.

### Half-solution

I can use the em unit to express height without knowing anything about the font but that still leaves the line height property which also affects the final line height.

Ideally I would prefer to inherit line height but if I override it to a known multiplier then I can force the box to become exactly two lines tall.

```
.progressStatus
{
    line-height: 1.1;
    height: 2.2em;
}
```

This solution is good enough for my needs but I'm curious if there's a better solution that does not involve javascript.

Comment: Don't think you can do that without something like LESS.  And even then, maybe not 100% dynamically.

Comment: This looks like a great solution to me.  I would be shocked if you could do better.

Comment: As opposed to overflow: hidden; you could look into ellipsis .truncate {
 width: 250px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

Comment: What about a little css transition to alleviate the jumping? Without a visual I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. hmmm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to express that in CSS.

> The status text inherits its appearance from the global style sheet and does not know font size, family, line height, or anything.

That's not quite correct. *Because* text in your status `div` inherits its values for `font-size`, `line-height`, etc. via the cascade, it "knows" these and will style itself accordingly. The problem is that CSS doesn't offer a way of using these values for calculations. They are only implicitly considered when declaring new properties.

The only way to achieve exactly what you want is via JavaScript. I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkoala/RXQuy/) using some jQuery. In my example, a simple `body` declaration acts as the ancestor. Run it with different `font-size` and `line-height` values in the body CSS.

In practice, I would combine this with your method as a fallback for scenarios where

1. JavaScript is disabled
2. the relevant ancestor's `line-height` is given as a percentage value (descendants inherit the *calculated* value) *and* you decide to change your status `font-size`. **Example:** The ancestor's `font-size` is `16px` and its `line-height` is `120%` (~ 19px). Now, if you decide your status needs more attention and declare `.progressStatus {font-size: 24px;}`, it will inherit the calculated `line-height` (still 19px). So you'd have a line-height smaller than the text size. Explicitly declaring a `line-height` as in your "half-solution" prevents that case from occuring.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  It can be done with only CSS. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864660/setting-the-height-to-a-div-to-a-multiple-of-line-height/73771995#73771995).

Answer (score 8):

The [CSS Values and Units Module Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/) proposes [the `lh` relative length unit](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#lh):

> Equal to the computed value of the ['line-height'](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) property of the element on which it is used, converting ['normal'](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#valdef-line-height-normal) to an absolute length by using only the metrics of the [first available font](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#first-available-font).

The current status of the document is shown under the page title. At the time of this writing, it is in the [working draft stage](https://www.w3.org/standards/types#WD). You can find [a list of open GitHub issues related to css-values-4 here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Acss-values-4).

Here's the caniuse page for the feature: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_lh.

Example:

```css
div {
  padding: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 7lh; /* 7 times the line-height */
}
```

```html
<div>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5</div>
```

---

Since the motivation for the question post here is to make *text* inside the div not resize the box, you might also want to change the values for the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property, and make sure that [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)'s computed value isn't being unintendedly set to `border-box` by other rules.

Answer (score 7):

```css
div {
  height: 1em; // that's one line, 2em for 2 lines, etc...
  line-height: 1em; // the height of one text line
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is not answering the question, since you're forcing line-height of 1em, while it can be 1.1 for example, like the example above.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe using a "shared" variable provides you with a close enough solution to achieve your desired "inherited line height". Declaring a variable avoids defining the line height twice. Taking up your example this solution sets a fixed height of `2.2em` (`1.1 * 2em = 2.2em` = 2 lines):

```css
.progressStatus
{
    height: calc(var(--line-height) * 2em);
    line-height: var(--line-height);
    --line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Change `2em` to `3em` to use 3 line heights (1.1 * 3em = 3.3em).

Optionally the variable `-line-height` can also be defined higher up in the DOM hierarchy if helpful as variables are visible in all nested elements, too, until overridden.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to the party, but if I have understood your requirement correctly, it IS possible to achieve exactly what you want entirely with inline HTML styling or with CSS, but not necessarily in the exact way you might have preferred to. I offer two possible solutions.

As is pointed out by you and others, some of the base attribute values required are not accessible. They are, however, obviously, available to the browser, because it has to do, and does do, the calculations to make blocks big enough to fit content, etc.

There is only a small amount of CSS required.

The HTML provided here in total is relatively long, but only because it includes two solutions and nine progress status text examples.  Only three DOM elements are required for either solution.

The trick in the approach in the two solutions I believe I have to your request, is to get the browser to do the calculation in a way the result can be implicitly or explicitly accessed by style attributes.

In this case it is the height of a block containing two lines of text.

So:

1. create two lines of text with '&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;'
2. put it in a block, which is then (for the purpose here) two lines high
3. put that block into a container block
4. the container block is then (for the purpose here) two lines high,
   ie, its minimum height has been implicitly set to two lines
5. put another block, the progress status block,  inside the container

The first solution 'inlines' the progress status block.

The second solution 'positions' the progress status block.

In both solutions, the progress status block can then jump between one and two lines of text as much as it needs without disturbing anything outside the container.

The first of the two solutions, Inline, allows three or more lines of text to expand the container. This happens because the computed height of the container is dependent on the flow of its contents which ultimately depends on the progress status text, so max height, or height, cannot be set to a value because by the time the container's height is accessible the computed height has already been changed by the browser from the initial two lines. If the occasional extra flow is not a problem, then all okay. But you cannot trim off what would otherwise be overflow, because the required height is not accessible.

The first solution uses the three CSS classes suffixed 'Inline'.

The second solution, Position, makes the container height accessible by decoupling the content flow of the progress status block from its container, using absolute positioning. This means the content of the  progress status block no longer affects the size of its container, ie, parent. So max height, or height, of the progress status block can be set to the height of its parent, which once decoupled is not recalculated (in this scenario), and, which in this case is the two lines. However, overflow must, I presume,  be hidden. Otherwise it will tramp over the edge of the container and anything else in its way. Note  also the background is constrained by the height setting, and does not follow the overflow text.

The second solution uses the three CSS classes suffixed 'Position'.

Either solution is readily adjustable to more than two lines; just add '<br>&nbsp;' for each extra line.

You may also want to add 'visibility: hidden;' to the Inline solution, as per the Position solution, to stop screen readers getting distracted by otherwise irrelevant content.

To have the background, if being used, in the Position solution also fill the container for one line of text, change max-height to height in the CSS class. For the Inline solution, move the background from the progress status block to the container block CSS class.

I have tried both solutions on Chrome on Windows and Chrome on Android.  It is very basic CSS and HTML so it should work universally?

```css
.progressStatusContainerInline {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.setHeightTwoLinesInline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0%;
}

.progressStatusInline {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
}

.progressStatusContainerPosition {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.setHeightTwoLinesPosition {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.progressStatusPosition {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
Inline examples with:
<ul>
<li>default line height</li>
<li>single line of text at bottom of status box</li>
<li>too much text expands status box</li>
</ul>
<div style="width: 200px;">
<div class="progressStatusContainerInline">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesInline">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusInline">
Progress status text line going to two lines.
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progressStatusContainerInline">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesInline">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusInline">
Short status text.
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progressStatusContainerInline">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesInline">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusInline">
Much much much much much much longer status text written here.
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>

Position examples with:
<ul>
<li>line height 3.5</li>
<li>single line of text at top of status box</li>
<li>too much text is truncated</li>
</ul>
<div style="line-height: 3.5; width: 200px;">
<div class="progressStatusContainerPosition">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesPosition">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusPosition">
Progress status text line going to two lines.
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progressStatusContainerPosition">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesPosition">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusPosition">
Short status text.
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progressStatusContainerPosition">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesPosition">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusPosition">
Much much much much much much longer status text written here.
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>

Position examples with:
<ul>
<li>line height 1.4</li>
<li>single line of text at top of status box</li>
<li>too much text is truncated</li>
</ul>
<div style="line-height: 1.4; width: 200px;">
<div class="progressStatusContainerPosition">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesPosition">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusPosition">
Progress status text line going to two lines.
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progressStatusContainerPosition">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesPosition">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusPosition">
Short status text.
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progressStatusContainerPosition">
<div class="setHeightTwoLinesPosition">&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;
</div><div class="progressStatusPosition">
Much much much much much much longer status text written here.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: great answer, worked in my use case. wish CSS supported this natively but overall this is one of the less janky tricks I've seen/used 

Answer (score 1):

You can use these on the div:

```
.your-div {
  line-height: 1.1em;
  max-height: 2.2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This will cause the end of text displayed as three dots (...) when it's more than two lines.